# Importing data from mysql error - Pipeline has terminated

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

[image]

Importing Data from mysql to Elastic Search through kibana 
Getting warn - Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified

and
 Pipeline has terminated {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#"}

and my conf

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "mysql-connector-java-5.1.46-bin.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
    jdbc_user => "root"
    jdbc_password => "***"
    statement => "SELECT * from Test"
  }
}


output{
   stdout { codec => json_lines }
  elasticsearch {
 "hosts" => "localhost:9200"
  "index" => "test-migrate"
  "document_type" => "data"
  }
}
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: Don't provide information as image which can be text.

Answer (score 1):

By default, if you are running a single query without using scheduling, logstash pipeline will be terminated once the query is processed. 
You need to enable Scheduling in `jdbc` input to run it periodically, as follows,

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "mysql-connector-java-5.1.46-bin.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
    schedule => "0 * * * *"
    jdbc_user => "root"
    jdbc_password => "***"
    statement => "SELECT * from Test"
  }
}
```

This will execute your query on **the 0th minute of every hour every day**.
The syntax for schedule is pretty much like cron-like. Please have a look [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#_scheduling_2) for syntax and more details.